# I don't know why it takes a long time to access the azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created an F1 Free Azure App Service running my current portfolio.
But.. If I check again after about an hour, I will not be able to access it.
If I wait another minute, I can reconnect, but I can't do that.
Isn't there a good way?
Should I use a LinuxVM or WindowsServerVM?

Comment: In App Service, the application will be unloaded if it is idle for 20 minutes (I think): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-availability-performance-application-issues#how-do-i-decrease-the-response-time-for-the-first-request-after-idle-time. Always On or some service sending a request to the application every 10 minutes can prevent this. Always On is not available in free tier though.

Comment: Thank you!! I appliciate your Answer!. I decide use Azure Virtual Marchine. Thank you

Comment: @juunas Your answer helped op, could you send your comment as an answer to help more users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App Service, the application will be unloaded if it is idle for 20 minutes (I think): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-availability-performance-application-issues#how-do-i-decrease-the-response-time-for-the-first-request-after-idle-time. Always On or some service sending a request to the application every 10 minutes can prevent this. Always On is not available in free tier though.

Comment: It really helped a lot. But in the end, the f1 layer cannot turn off the unload setting. Thank you.